# How to write a driver for java regarding a lockable interface?

Tags: java, interface, driver

The goal of this code is to have a lockable interface for my main class, `Coin`, that makes the user input a `key` to access the main code. However, I have no idea on how to write the driver class in a way where the lockable object protects the regular methods (`setKey`, `lock`, and `unlock`) and when this object is locked, the methods cannot be invoked if it is unlocked it can be invoked. I have attempted a driver but it doesn't work.

```
package coins;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coins {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess;
    System.out.println("Enter key: ");
    guess = scan.nextInt();
    Coin key = new Coin();
    System.out.println(key);

    final int flips = 1000;
    int heads = 0, tails=0;

    Coin myCoin = new Coin ();

    for (int  count =1; count <= flips; count++) {
      myCoin.flip();

      if (myCoin.isHeads())
        heads++;
      else
        tails++;
    }
    System.out.println ("The number flips: " + flips);
    System.out.println ("The number of heads: " + heads);
    System.out.println ("The number of tails: " + tails);
  }
}
```

Coin Class

```
package coins;


class Coin implements Lockable {
  private final int HEADS = 0;
  private final int TAILS = 1;
  private boolean locked;
  private int key;
  private int face;

  public Coin () {
    flip();
    locked = false;
    key = 123;
  }

  public void flip() {
    face = (int) (Math.random()*2);
  }

  public boolean isHeads() {
    return (face == HEADS);
  }

  public String toString() {
    String faceName;
    if (face == HEADS)
      faceName = "Heads";
    else
      faceName = "Tails";
      return faceName;
  }

  public boolean locked(){
    return locked;
  }
  public void setKey(int key){
    this.key = key;
  }
  public void unlock(int key){
    if(this.key == key){
      locked = false ;
    }
  }
  public void lock(int key){
    if(this.key == key){
      locked = true;
    }
  }
  public void messageReturn(){
    if(locked == false)
      System.out.println("unlocked") ;
    }
  }
```

Lockable Interface

```
public interface Lockable {
  public void setKey (int key);
  public void lock (int key);
  public void unlock (int key);
  public boolean locked();
}
```

Comment: You did it just right. I don't see a problem

Comment: Whenever I enter a number, it still runs my code when the key is wrong. When I enter the right key it doesn't print the message.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should check if the guess is correct via: (in `main`)

```
key.unlock(guess);//and you might want to set the default of locked to true, and remove the flip() in the constructor
```

You need to add a check in each method:

```
public void flip()
{
    if(!locked)
        face = (int) (Math.random()*2);
}
```

similarly with other methods.

Comment: I removed the flip() and I am confused as to if I add key.unlock(guess) in the main code or the constructor.

Comment: After adding it to the main code, it still fails to hold any restrictions

Answer (score 0):

What Itamar Green is saying is true. However, to me, it appears that the real problem you are describing is in your `Coins` class, and not the `Coin` class. You aren't actually doing anything with the `guess` key that the user enters. You need to call `setKey()` on the `Coin` using that key. Then, your `Coin` will invoke or not invoke methods as per your code and Itamar's answer, by first checking to see whether it is in the locked state.

Comment: Can I try making the variable static so I can reach it among classes and compare them in the main code?

Comment: I think that might be OK if you want to have a single key for all of your coins. But if you want to have a different key per coin, then a static key would be wrong approach.

Comment: I would like to just have a single key but for some reason I can't make the variable static! It keeps giving me errors

Comment: Search on Google and here on StackOverflow for details on what this new error means. If that doesn't work, consider creating a new question to find an answer for this new error and add a comment or edit on your question linking this question to the new one.